# Finding digit root

Tags: java

I need some help checking over my program to find the digit root. If a user enters 5635 the digit root is 1. To find the digit root of a number you add all the digits in the number 5 + 6 + 3 + 5 and you get the result of 19. Then you add the result 1 + 9 = 10. Then you add 1 + 0 until you get 1 which is your digit root.

1. Do i have the right approach or is my approach to the question totally off?
2. Why am i getting 0 as the result instead of the correct answer of 1?

```
import acm.program.*; 

public class DigitRoot extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {
        println("this program attemts to find the digit root a user enters.");

        int n = readInt("please enter any positive integer: ");

        int dsum = 0;
        int sumtotal = 0;
        int threesum = 0;
        int foursum = 0;

        while (n > 0) {
            dsum += n % 10;
            n /= 10;

            if (dsum > 9) {
                sumtotal = (dsum / 10) + (dsum % 10);
            } else if (sumtotal > 9) {
                threesum = (sumtotal / 10) + (sumtotal % 10);
            } else if (threesum > 9) {
                foursum = (threesum / 10) + (threesum % 10);
            } else if (foursum < 9) {
                println("your digit root is" + foursum);
            } else {
                println("this program is borken.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way. I suggest take the input as `String`, this way the manipulations you want to do are way easier.

Comment: @m0skit0 what should i do?

Comment: Format it so we can read it...

Comment: This is well suited for a recursion: calculate the sum of the numbers, if the result is > 9 calculate the sum of the sum etc... else return the result.

Comment: @kent yes sorry that was a typo. I just edited it.

Comment: No recursion needed really, simple loop will do and looks nicer in language like Java. But get rid of `sumtotal`, `threesum` and `foursum`, just keep using dsum in a loop...

Comment: @assylias that's what I'm attempting to do but I think i've made it more confusing than it needs to be. Can you give me an example of how to solve this problem with recursion.

Comment: @hyde I think a recursion in this case is very readable and as simple.

Comment: @hyde I have not learned about strings yet. That is in two chapters. Is there a way to solve the problem with for/while loops and if/ else statements?

Comment: @assylias Matter of opinion... Difference is really very minor in syntax, but since Java does not support tail call optimization, loop is both more efficient, and more importantly, safer as a pattern (no need to consider recursion depth, though in this case it's *log10* so safe).

Comment: @JessicaM. There's really no need to involve chars or strings here, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using a recursion - I calculate the sum of the figures by using a String: it is not very efficient but is (slightly) easier. Feel free to improve by using `n % 10` in a loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(calculateRoot(5635)); //prints 1
}

public static int calculateRoot(int n) {
    int sum = sumFigures(n);
    return sum < 10 ? sum : calculateRoot(sum);
}

public static int sumFigures(int n) {
    String s = String.valueOf(n);
    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        sum += c - '0';
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some math tells you that this is just the remainder when you divide by 9 (We replace a remainder of 0 by 9). The following works for `n > 0`:

```
int root = n % 9;
if (root == 0) root = 9;
```

Comment: Good idea. You need to take care to handle `n==0` correctly, though.

Comment: @user1252434 yes thanks, I assumed n would be > 0. Clarified answer.

Comment: Or, for n >= 0: `int root = 1 + ((n - 1) % 9);`

Comment: Or, for all numbers (including negative): `int root = 1 + ((Math.abs(n) - 1) % 9)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
int n = 5635;
int total = 0;
do {
    while (n > 0) {
        total = total + (n % 10);
        n = (n / 10);
    }
    n = total;
    total = 0;
} while (n > 9);
System.out.println(n);
```

**Or using recurssion,**

```
    int n = 5635;
    int total = 0;

    do {
        total = Test.sumofdigit(n);
        n = total;
    } while (total >= 10);

    System.out.println(total);


public static int sumofdigit(int inputnumber) {
    if (inputnumber < 10)
        return inputnumber;
    return sumofdigit(inputnumber / 10) + inputnumber % 10;
}
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar solution. You can turn around the outer while loop (`while (n>9) { ... }`) in the general case, saves one iteration when n has only one digit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems very complex..Try this

```
while ( n > 0 ) {
                dsum +=  n % 10;
                n /= 10;
                if(n==0 && dsum >9){
                    n=dsum;
                    dsum =0;
                }

        }
        System.out.println(dsum);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about playing with chars?

```
@Test
    public void testGetRoot(){
        int n=3565;
        char[] chars;
        while (n>9){
            int r=0;
            chars = String.valueOf(n).toCharArray();
            for(char c : chars)r+=(c-'0');
            n=r;
        }
        System.out.println(n);
    }
```

this will output 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two-function version of the nested-loops solution in another answer, perhaps easier to understand:

```
int digitRoot(int num) {
  // calculate digit root as specified:
  // get sum of digits until there is only one digit, which is the root
  while (num > 9) {
    num = sumOfDigits(num);
  }
  return num;
}

int sumOfDigits(int num) {
  int sum = 0;
  // negative numbers not supported, for them 0 is returned...
  while (num > 0) {
    sum += num % 10; // add least significant digit's value to sum
    num /= 10; // remove the least significant digit from num
  }
  return sum;
}
```